# Reading JSON data with jquery. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to read JSON data using jquery. Specifically I'm trying to read the JSON from this url: http://mkweb.bcgsc.ca/color-summarizer/?url=http://scontent-a.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfa1/t51.2885-15/10643840_701797013239098_657737630_a.jpg&precision=low&num_clusters=3&json=1&callback=?

However I keep getting this error:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :` 

Here is my jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        var one = "1"

        $.getJSON('http://mkweb.bcgsc.ca/color-summarizer/?url=http://scontent-a.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfa1/t51.2885-15/10643840_701797013239098_657737630_a.jpg&precision=low&num_clusters=3&json=1&callback=?', function(result) {

            document.write(result.clusters.one.rgb[0]);

        });
    });
```

I'm getting the error at the very first colon in the JSON code.

From what I understand, the JSON data is actually being read as Javascript. How can I fix this.

Comment: The url doesn't support JSONP or at least doesn't support providing a `callback=xyz` parameter.

Comment: Unrelated, but your `var one` trick isn't going to work. You'll need to use `result.clusters[one].rgb[0]` or `result.clusters['1'].rgb[0]`

Comment: I added the callback=? parameter as I was previously getting this error `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the [API Docs](http://mkweb.bcgsc.ca/color-summarizer/?api) I found that you need to specify a `jsnop=1` parameter in order to retrieve data via JSONP.

Tthe correct code would be something like this:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {         
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://mkweb.bcgsc.ca/color-summarizer/',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonpCallback: 'colorsummary',
            data:{
                url: 'http://scontent-a.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfa1/t51.2885-15/10643840_701797013239098_657737630_a.jpg',
                precision: 'low',
                num_clusters: '3',
                jsonp: '1'
            },
            success: function(result){
                document.write(result.clusters['1'].rgb[0]);
            }
        });
    });
```

I also structured the request so you can change parameters easily.

PS: watch out with that JSON notation ( the ['1'] in clusters and so)

Comment: No. Refering to the API docs, $.getJSON() is a short handle for an ajax call. See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: I was talking about the color-summarizer API. I used $.ajax() just in order to manage more easily the request.